# React- Webpack: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, django-webpack-loader

I have a React application configured with Django Application. I have different webpack config files for development and production, When I run "npm run start", it gives me error that:

> Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

**package.json file:**

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "ajv": "^6.5.4",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^5.0.4",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.4",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
],
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
        "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
        "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx}",
        "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$",
        "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
        "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "web.js",
        "js",
        "json",
        "web.jsx",
        "jsx",
        "node"
    ]
},
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        "react-app"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
       "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
       "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0",
       "tap": "^11.0.0-rc.3",
       "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.2-beta",
       "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.dev.js file:
    "use strict";

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require("pnp-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths- 
webpack-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev- 
 utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin");
 const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require("react-dev- 
  utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin");
  const ModuleScopePlugin = require("react-dev- 
  utils/ModuleScopePlugin");
  const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require("react-dev- 
     utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent");
 const getClientEnvironment = require("./env");
 const paths = require("./paths");
 const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");
 const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require("react-dev- 
utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin");

 // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being 
served from.
 // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config 
 easier.
 //const publicPath = '/';
 // `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
 // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in 
 JavaScript.
 // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than 
       %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.

    const publicPath = "http://localhost:3000/";
   const publicUrl = "http://localhost:3000/";
     // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
    const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);
   const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");
    // style files regexes
     const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
     const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
    const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
 const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

 // common function to get style loaders
 const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    require.resolve("style-loader"),
     {
           loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
           options: cssOptions
      },
     {
  // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
  // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
  // package.json
  loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
  options: {
    // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
    ident: "postcss",
    plugins: () => [
      require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
      require("postcss-preset-env")({
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: "no-2009"
        },
        stage: 3
      })
    ]
  }
   }
 ];
 if (preProcessor) {
   loaders.push(require.resolve(preProcessor));
 }
 return loaders;
};

 // This is the development configuration.
 // It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
 // The production configuration is different and lives in a separate 
    file.
   module.exports = {
      mode: "development",
       // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
       // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/343
     devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
   // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: [
        // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
      // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
     // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
           // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
   // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
     // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
      // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
       // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
       // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
     require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
     require.resolve("webpack-dev-server/client") + "? 
     http://localhost:3000",
     require.resolve("webpack/hot/dev-server"),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      paths.appIndexJs
        // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
// initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
   output: {
     // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: true,
          // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
       // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
       filename: "static/js/bundle.js",
// There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
// This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
publicPath: publicPath,
// Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
  path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
  },
   optimization: {
     // Automatically split vendor and commons
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
splitChunks: {
  chunks: "all",
  name: false
},
minimize: false,
// Keep the runtime chunk seperated to enable long term caching
// https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
    runtimeChunk: true
  },
   resolve: {
// This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
// We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
// if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
modules: ["node_modules"].concat(
  // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
  process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
),
// These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
// We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
// some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
// `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
// for React Native Web.
extensions: [".mjs", ".web.js", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx"],
alias: {
  // Support React Native Web
  // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
  "react-native": "react-native-web"
},
plugins: [
  // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
  // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
  PnpWebpackPlugin,
  // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
  // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
  // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
  // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
  // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
  new BundleTracker({
    path: paths.statsRoot,
    filename: "webpack-stats.dev.json"
  }),
  new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson])
]
 },
   resolveLoader: {
plugins: [
  // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
  // from the current package.
  PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module)
]
  },
  module: {
strictExportPresence: true,
rules: [
  // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
  { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

  // First, run the linter.
  // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
  {
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
    enforce: "pre",
    use: [
      {
        options: {
          formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
          eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint")
        },
        loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader")
      }
    ],
    include: paths.appSrc
  },
  {
    // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
    // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
    // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
    oneOf: [
      // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
      // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
      // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
      {
        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
        }
      },
      // Process application JS with Babel.
      // The preset includes JSX, Flow, and some ESnext features.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
        options: {
          customize: require.resolve(
            "babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"
          ),

             plugins: [
            [
              require.resolve("babel-plugin-named-asset-import"),
              {
                loaderMap: {
                  svg: {
                    ReactComponent: "@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          ],
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
          // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
          cacheCompression: false
        }
      },
      // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
      // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
        loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          configFile: false,
          compact: false,
          presets: [
            [
              require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"),
              { helpers: true }
            ]
          ],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
          cacheCompression: false,

          // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
          // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
          // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
          // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
          sourceMaps: false
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssRegex,
        exclude: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1
        })
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
      // using the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
        })
      },
      // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
      // Chains the sass-loader with the css-loader and the style-loader
      // to immediately apply all styles to the DOM.
      // By default we support SASS Modules with the
      // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        exclude: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({ importLoaders: 2 }, "sass-loader")
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
      // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders(
          {
            importLoaders: 2,
            modules: true,
            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
          },
          "sass-loader"
        )
      },
      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
      // that fall through the other loaders.
      {
        // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
        // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
        // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
        // by webpacks internal loaders.
        exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
        options: {
          name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
  // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
]
 },
   plugins: [
// Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: paths.appHtml
}),

// new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
//   name: "xu"
// }),
// Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
// The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
// <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
// In development, this will be an empty string.
new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
// This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
// the requesting resource.
new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
// Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
// This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
// Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
// a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
// See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
// If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
// to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
// makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
// See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
// Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
// by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
// solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
// https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
// You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
// Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
// to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
// having to parse `index.html`.
new ManifestPlugin({
  fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
  publicPath: publicPath
})
 ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
dgram: "empty",
fs: "empty",
net: "empty",
tls: "empty",
child_process: "empty"
 },
     // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
   // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
 performance: false
};
```

start.js file:
       "use strict";

```
      // Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
   process.env.BABEL_ENV = "development";
   process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";

  // Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
   // ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
  // terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
   process.on("unhandledRejection", err => {
      throw err;
   });

   // Ensure environment variables are read.
  require("../config/env");

   const fs = require("fs");
  const chalk = require("chalk");
  const webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");
const clearConsole = require("react-dev-utils/clearConsole");
const checkRequiredFiles = require("react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles");
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
 prepareProxy,
 prepareUrls
} = require("react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils");
 const openBrowser = require("react-dev-utils/openBrowser");
 const paths = require("../config/paths");
 const config = require("../config/webpack.config.dev");
 const createDevServerConfig = 
 require("../config/webpackDevServer.config");

 const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
 const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

 // Warn and crash if required files are missing
 if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
        process.exit(1);
  }

 // Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
      const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
  const HOST = process.env.HOST || "0.0.0.0";

 if (process.env.HOST) {
    console.log(
     chalk.cyan(
  `   Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ${chalk.yellow(
    chalk.bold(process.env.HOST)
  )}`
  )
 );
   console.log(
   `If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.`
  );
      console.log(
     `Learn more here:`
   );
 console.log();
}

         // We require that you explictly set browsers and do not fall 
    back to
  // browserslist defaults.
    const { checkBrowsers } = require("react-dev-utils/browsersHelper");
      checkBrowsers(paths.appPath, isInteractive)
     .then(() => {
           // We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
         // run on a different port. `choosePort()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
        return choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT);
      })
       .then(port => {
       if (port == null) {
          // We have not found a port.
         return;
         }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === "true" ? "https" : "http";
const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
// Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
// Load proxy config
const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
// Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web server.
const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
  proxyConfig,
  urls.lanUrlForConfig
);
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
// Launch WebpackDevServer.
devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  if (isInteractive) {
    clearConsole();
  }
  console.log(chalk.cyan("Starting the development server...\n"));
  openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
});

["SIGINT", "SIGTERM"].forEach(function(sig) {
  process.on(sig, function() {
    devServer.close();
    process.exit();
  });
});
 })
 .catch(err => {
   if (err && err.message) {
     console.log(err.message);
   }
   process.exit(1);
 });
```

Error Stacktrace:

```
> project@0.1.0 start /usr/react_projects/project
> node scripts/start.js

 Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I don't understand why it is giving Cannot find property "tap" undefined.

Comment: This error is not in package.json file, paste full error from console please

Comment: tap errors are usually when a plugin is not compatible with webpack 4, but since you didn't think it would be useful to show the error stack trace so we know what module is throwing it's hard to know

Comment: @Dominic I have edited my answer with the full error stacktrace.

Comment: @ReemaParakh to be fair the stack trace doesn't give much. PS You have a lot of dependencies that should be in devDependencies and I doubt you need to declare tap as one. This build script looks messy and over complicated, I would suggest you either start again or remove pieces of it like any plugins until it starts compiling to find which module has issues.

Comment: @Dominic I have followed this- http://v1k45.com/blog/modern-django-part-1-setting-up-django-and-react/ link to integrate the project

Comment: I wouldn't bother with that overly complex tutorial, there are better ones or just generate a react app using facebook's "create-react-app" which has no config. Your backend should be an API that serves pure JSON data so it lives separately to the UI project anyway so you don't need something django specific.

Comment: @ReemaParakh is this problem resolved  ???- I am facing the same issue .. if you can suggest any better aproach you followed could you please share it ?

Comment: @BikiranDas No, I didn't found the solution to this problem. Tried everything, and then after searching alot about SSR, I moved to NextJS, which a React framework that comes with inbuilt SSR support. And also as suggested by Dominic I have kept my backend API part different from the frontent.

Comment: @ReemaParakh I have bulit it seperate and found its better to consume the Backend API using the fromnt end react app seperately - for beginner

Comment: @BikiranDas yes, I did the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProgressPlugin TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227877/progressplugin-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tap-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. You have to add `@babel/preset-react` library to your **package.json** file.

Run yarn `yarn add @babel/preset-react` or `npm install @babel/preset-react`

[image: Dev dependencies screenshot]