# Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin' after I updated to nextjs@10.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

After I updated to nextjs `10.1.3` I had an error when I launch `yarn dev`.

```
error - ./public/static/style.scss
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
Require stack:
- /path_to/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle4.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/config-utils.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/config.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /path_to/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next

Could not find files for /[lang] in .next/build-manifest.json
Could not find files for /[lang] in .next/build-manifest.json
event - compiled successfully
```

I found that [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179531/error-cannot-find-module-webpack-lib-node-nodetemplateplugin) but it did not solve my problem.

I removed packages and lock files, and also tried to install webpack etc [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43201878/7942242).

Which drove me to another error about `tap` what drove me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53677725/7942242) so I remove what I just did, so back to the first error above.

Here is my `next.config.js`

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        });
        return config;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Have you [enabled webpack 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124104/how-to-use-webpack-5-configs-in-next-js/66125274#66125274) in Next.js config, or are you still using webpack 4?

Comment: I tried, but didn't change anything :/

Comment: I finally got back to next@9.3.6. It seems that multiple things has change and the way they handle some stuff are different. 
For most people they'd have to remove @zeit deps I guess

Comment: You don't need `@zeit/next-sass` and `@zeit/next-css` anymore. There's [built-in support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) for it in Next.js now.

Comment: Yes I got that, but the way I handle multi-languages did a strange bug :/. The website reloaded infinitely. So I don't want to lose too much time on this. But thanks

Answer (score 3):

so I have similar setup as what you have i.e Next.js with Antd and Less. I got this error recently after upgrading to the latest version of nextjs (10.2.0). Fortunately for me, I stumbled on this question and clicked on the Similar issue link you attached and I got the solution from there. I resolved this by installing `webpack`

`npm i webpack@webpack-4 --save-dev`

Hopefully this would save someone else's time :). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In my case the project to be maintained consists of Next.js (9.3.2), Antd, Less, Typescript.

Simply REVERT what you have done to fix this problem first, and then run the command:

```
yarn upgrade next 10.2.3
yarn add webpack@webpack-4 --dev
```

Patience is one of the keys I got in this journey.

The scenario of updating next.js version breakdown is here:

- static export;
- getStaticPaths NEEDS the fetch() method in my case, even someone says it should not be done;
- fetch() is browser dependent, which suppose not to be work server-side;
- installing `yarn add isomorphic-unfetch` will not aid anything, thus upgrade next.js version is the only option
- next >= 10.0.0 has the handy fix, after several hours researching, next 10.2.3 does the best, no need to change the version of typescript (^3.7.5), etc;
- finally when running the command: `next build && next export`,
  the top stack `mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js` locates the error `Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'`
- run `yarn add webpack@webpack-4 --dev`;
- re-run `next build && next export`